# Exporting Runnable JAR in eclipse with User Libraries included

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, export, libraries

I am trying to create a runnable JAR file from a project of which I'm importing org.apache.commons.io. I tried exporting and checked the box to include all dependant libraries but I keep getting this output:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/io
/filefilter/TrueFileFilter
        at tvSort.Main.main(Main.java:36)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.io.filefilter.Tr
ueFileFilter
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 1 more
```

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: I don't have Eclipse in front of me right now to give you exact steps, but in the build path settings (where you add JARs to your build path) there should be a tab that has to do with "exports"; go there, and be sure your required libraries are selected. This tab controls which of your build path libraries are actually exported with the project (which is independent of the build path itself).

Comment: I checked Build Path -> Order and Export. I selected the apache library and I am still getting the same output

Comment: Did you select it in "Order and Export" *and* "Package required libraries into generated jar" when exporting the runnable JAR? Have you selected the correct run configuration on the runnable JAR export dialog? Try removing your existing run configurations for that project then creating a new one (by running it), perhaps theres strange settings in your current one. Also check the run configuration's "classpath" tab (normally Eclipse sets it up automatically, though)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try setting up classpath in the Manifest?

e.g. Class-Path: commons-io-xyzversion.jar

If you can please try to add this manifest entry manually by saving this in a text file and adding it via the jar tool.

Hopefully eclipse has already done this,so did you run the jar with dependencies(jars) in the same folder/path?